# replace non-zero values with random numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a zero-one matrix in MATLAB as follows:

```
[0 0 0 1 1 1
 0 1 1 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 1
 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 1]
```

I want to define another matrix including rand values instead of indexes of above matrix by `1`. For instance the desired new rand matrix should be:

```
[0 0 0 0.2 0.2 0.1
 0 0.6 0.7 0 0 0
 0.4 0 0 0 0 0.6
 0.7 0.8 0.5 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0.3 0 0.4]
```

I used a `two nested loop for` to find non-zero values from first matrix and replace the rand values instead of them in a new matrix.

Is there any function of matlab to do it automatically, without using `two nested loop for`?

Comment: You can just multiply the matrices, without any loops.

Comment: @Adiel - it's actually right. But it would require a zero-one matrix, like stated in the question. The question title says non-zero values, which would require the transformation to logical first. It's not entirely clear. But for the first case, your approach is a little faster.

Comment: Actually you right, but i took only the case in the question, didn't notice the difference in the title. But, he says that's the matrix he has... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
A = ...
[0 0 0 1 1 1;
 0 1 1 0 0 0;
 1 0 0 0 0 1;
 1 1 1 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 1 0 1];

B = rand(size(A));
A(logical(A)) = B(logical(A));

A =

         0         0         0    0.1320    0.2348    0.1690
         0    0.3377    0.3897         0         0         0
    0.9027         0         0         0         0    0.7317
    0.9448    0.3692    0.4039         0         0         0
         0         0         0    0.0598         0    0.4509
```

(I just took the basic `rand`-function, adjust it, as you need it)

Answer (score 4):

You can slightly improve [thewaywewalk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818910/2586922) by generating only as many random numbers as you need. As a bonus, this approach allows to do everything in one line:

```
A(logical(A)) = rand(1,nnz(A));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to replace the ones in matrix A with random numbers then you don't need any looping at all.

Here's one method.

```
a = double(rand(5,5)>.5); % Your binary matrix should be type double.
n = sum(a(:));            % Count the 1's.
a(a>0) = rand(1,n);       % Replace the ones with rands.
```

Comment: You can use `nnz(a)` to count non zero values and then `logical(a)` instead of `a>0`. Should add up to the computational efficiency in large problems.

Comment: This is a much more efficient solution in general as it only requires the number of random values needed to be generated.

Comment: @OlegKomarov, nice, didn't know about the nnz function. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If 'l' is a matrix containing zeros and non-zeros. Consider the scenarios below answering this question :

1. Replace all the zeros in matrix with random numbers :

   ```
   l(l==0) = randn(1,size(l(l==0),1));
   ```
2. Replace all the positive values with random numbers :

   ```
   l(l>0) = randn(1,size(l(l>0),1));
   ```
3. Replace all the negative values with random numbers :

   ```
   l(l<0) = randn(1,size(l(l<0),1));
   ```
4. Replace all the 'NaN' with  random numbers.

   ```
   l(isnan(l)) = randn(1,size(l(isnan(l)),1));
   ```

Comment: None of these solutions will actually replace *all nonzero values* in the matrix (for any matrix), as was requested in the question.

Comment: Points 2, 3 and 4 will will replace all the nonzero values in the matrix (for any matrix) with different **random numbers**.  If you want to replace them with a specific number, then you can use  operator   l(l<0) = 222, it will replace all the negative values in matrix $l$ with 222.

Comment: First, point 1 has nothing to do with the question. In fact, it does the exact *opposite* of what was requested. Second, why do 2, 3, and 4 when `l(l~=0) = randn(1,size(l(l~=0),1));` is sufficient? This question already had a number of satisfactory answers, and I'm sad to say that this one does not provide much added value.

Comment: Your point is valid, but in my answer I tried to explain other scenarios also like replacing positives/negatives/zeros separately in a matrix.  Of course we can play with operators to do different stuff differently.